# Need to update the database without navigating to another page in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic asp page that fetches data from a table. I have a button to update some values in the database. This is the code I have used.

Code in SelectData.asp

```
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="location.href='RecordsUpdate.asp'"></p>
```

When I click the button it redirects to RecordsUpdate.asp page and updates the database (RecordsUpdate.asp has the code to update the database and it's working fine). I need to update the database but I don't want to navigate to RecordsUpdate.asp page. I need to stay on SelectData.asp page itself, but when I click the button the data should be updated in the database. How can I do that?

Please help me out.

Thanks In Advance,
Abhilash D K

Comment: What have you already tried? If the answer is nothing then you don't deserve an answer. SO is not here as a quick *"give me the code to do this"* it is here to provide quality answers to quality questions that help the SO community as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be best off using jQuery for this so you can capture the button 'onclick' and use Ajax to "get" the RecordsUpdate.asp page:

```
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Reset">

<script>
$("#mybutton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get( "RecordsUpdate.asp", function( data ) {
        //data will be the output from `RecordsUpdate.asp`
        alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi,Thank You for the reply. But I tried the code and nothing is happening even the alert is not showing nor the database is being updated. I am setting some session variable. If I use jQuery to navigate to the page will the other page be able to use the session variable.

Comment: Do you get an error? Is the "RecordsUpdate.asp" page being hit? You will need to put the relative path in the $.get("...") call. It might be that you need to change the $.get to a $.post (depending on how "RecordsUpdate.asp" is set up. Also, make sure your button has the additional "id" attribute.

Comment: The OP just wants a quick fix, don't pander to them. They probably haven't even realised that your solution uses jQuery and so will need to include the jQuery library. This is why answering these types of questions is pointless until the OP shows some degree of effort.

Comment: Ok Lankymart - new to the site and trying to make a good impression. ;-) *steps away from the post*

Comment: @scgough I'm not trying to discourage you from answering questions just don't be too quick to jump on questions that show no attempt that approaching the problem themselves. [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I have included the jquery library jquery-1.10.2.js in the script tag. I even changed the $.get() to $.post() and my button has an id attribute and I have set it to "mybutton" itself. Still not getting any result. Can you help.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to call an .asp page without navigating to it. This the code that I used.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#updatebutton").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "RecordsUpdate.asp"
                    })
                .done(function (msg) {
                    alert("Data Saved");
                });
            });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank You all for helping me out.

Abhilash D K

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with javascript. Look here for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

If you are using jQuery, use this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

With the success callback you can retrieve some responsedata so you can notify the user if you want. This ain't rocket science.